# Change where Visual Studio default settings on startup?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, settings

I like to keep my folders quite organised, and don't like the default Visual Studio folder in my documents. It seems like it should be rather simple to point VS to my own custom folders for most of its settings, which I have done. The only problem is, on start up, VS keeps looking for a settings file (*.vssettings file) in a (non-existent) default folder which I can't seem to find any option to change (c:\users\renzo\documents\visual studio 2013\settings), making the IDE revert to most recent settings (the custom settings file I have created in a nice separate folder... which is fine, but accompanied by an annoying error message). If I so much as touch the tools-options menu (literally, without changing anything) VS then creates a new folder (in that same annoying default location!) storing my current settings! The cycle repeats!

Is there anyway to change where VS looks for these default *.vssettings files, and stop creating this new irritating "CurrentSettings.vssettings" file!?

Might seem a bit nit-picky, but its really getting under my skin!

Thanks,
Renzo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [mklink](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx) to change directory or file location to what you want. Choose one of the commands below.

```
mklink /d d:\VisualStudio c:\users\renzo\documents\visual studio 2013
mklink /d d:\VisualStudioSettings c:\users\renzo\documents\visual studio 2013\settings
mklink d:\VisualStudioSettings\CurrentSettings.vssettings "d:\VisualStudioSettings c:\users\renzo\documents\visual studio 2013\settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings"
```

Comment: Could you expand on that? I understand Mklink is used to create symbolic links, are you suggesting to create a symbolic link between the location VS looks for and my custom location? I am new to the Windows environment.

Comment: Yes I am suggesting that. Create a link for folder or settings file

Comment: Good concise answer which sorted the problem nicely! Thanks.